# MVC3 browser error...'sessionStorage' is undefined

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, session, browser, storage

I have an MVC3 C# .Net web app.  The app works fine when launching the website from external browsers (i.e., the browser on my machine and other users' machine).  However, when launched on the web server itself, I receive the following error

```
'sessionStorage' is undefined
```

...when loading an web page.  It's the type of error that displays the little yellow icon at the bottom of the browser.

Any ideas?  I must be missing on the server's browser.

Comment: What browser version? It looks like a problem with your Javascript.

Comment: @SLaks.....IE 7....I think that's the issue.  I googled the error and IE7 doesn't support that functionality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE7 doesn't support [sessionStorage](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/html5.html#t00). You can use it starting from IE8.